# Scala json extracting

Tags: json, scala

I am trying to extract data out of "entries" from this piece of json data.

```
{"20313890": [{
   "queue": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
   "name": "Orianna's Reapers",
   "entries": [{
      "leaguePoints": 51,
      "isFreshBlood": false,
      "isHotStreak": false,
      "division": "V",
      "isInactive": false,
      "isVeteran": false,
      "losses": 6,
      "playerOrTeamName": "iPrototype",
      "playerOrTeamId": "20313890",
      "wins": 10
   }],
   "tier": "SILVER"
}]}
```

But I just can't figure out how to do it. I have this atm:

```
case class rankedStats(queue: String, name: String,entries: List[JObject], tier: String)
val elements = (json \\ "20313890").children
for (element <- elements) {
  val m = element.extract[rankedStats]
  println(m.queue)
}
```

I don't know what to do now I got this and I don't know if Im going in the right direction. 
Can you help me go through with this?

Please note Im really new to Scala!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found the answer!

```
case class listStats(leaguePoints: Int, division: String, losses: Int, wins: Int)
val e = m.entries
val o = e(0).extract[listStats]
println(o.division)
```

I just needed to make a new case class for the entries list and extract it.